# jQuery assign an href link to its parent element

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, parent-child

I'm hoping to make a `<td>` cell click-able with the link that is inside it. Code:

```
<td class="block">
    <a href="expansion/r10_01.htm">text goes here</a>
</td>
```

So when the user clicks anywhere in that cell the link activates rather than just on the text. There are various margins and padding set on the cell that stops the a href from expanding to fill the whole cell. There will also be a lot of cells to apply this to with different links in each one.

As always, any help appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options: Use CSS to set the  to fill the table cell so that it will be clicked by the user.

OR:

Use JQuery...

```
$('.block').click(function() {
  $('a', this).click();
});
```

This will fire the click event on the link and it will follow its default behavior.

Comment: This works nicely and carries over some extra parameters with the link which is great though it seems to trigger other effects on the page for some reason. Think i'm picking up a conflict somewhere unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("td.block").click(function() 
    {
        var url = $("a", $(this)).attr("href");
        document.location = url;
    });
});
```

Comment: THanks, this works though if I have extra code after the link ( i should have pointed this out) it doesn't carry over.For example: <a href="expansion/r01_l01.htm?KeepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&height=400&width=600" class="thickbox">

Comment: If you're trying to launch a thickbox window, you may want to consider js1568's solution. That actually triggers a click event on the href as if it were actually clicked. That should keep allow the thickbox to function as normal.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean?  The document's location should be redirected to whatever the entire value is set to in the `href` attribute's value.  Are you building the `href`'s value dynamically or something?

Comment: No it's not built dynamically, it just doesn't seem to take anything after the ? in the link. I guess the issue is that it doesn't know that it's a thickbox link as that value doesn't seem to get copied with the href. As mentioned above, js1568's solution works well, it just causes a small conflict with an accordian effect. THanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

When you click the td you need to get the attribute of the href:

```
$('td.block').click(function(){

   // get the href
   var thisHref = $(this).find('a').attr('href');

   location.href = thisHref;

});
```

[jsbin example link](http://jsbin.com/ekeri3)